# jaxws noSuchMethodError in javax/wsdl/Operation.getExtensibilityElements

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, webservice-client, spring-ws

When I create a ws client in IBM WAS 6.1 as a dynamic project the client works just fine.

But when we do the same thing and try to integrate the client in an existing project which has many other jars we get the following error just before we try to get the reference of the port we get this error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/wsdl/Operation.getExtensibilityElements()Ljava/util/List;
```

I am not sure if this is to do with some jar version issue or some jar conflict issue as the existing project has many jars.

When debugging I do see this class in the classpath  under 2 jars :

1. com.ibm.ws.runtime_6.1.0.jar
2. com.ibm.jaxws.thinclient_6.1.0.jar

the runtime has the BindignOperation with the getExtensibilityElements method but the thinclient does not.

since runtime is in the plugins folder it gets loaded first , also I think this is not a problem as some other project has the same env and it works but a different set of jars, since there are so many jars its difficult to find out which one could be a possible candidate for this issue

I dont think there is any problem with the webservice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am encountering this same problem and wanted to share my progress in case it helps anyone that comes across this question as I did.

I was able to find [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-java-user/200707.mbox/%3C562242.59595.qm@web37302.mail.mud.yahoo.com%3E), which suggests fixing the issue by using a single classloader for the application server in parent-last mode, which you can learn about [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzamy%2F50%2Fprogram%2Fclsiso.htm) and [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fcrun_classload.html) respectively.

I'm not sure if this would help with your original problem, but may help with similar issues.